# Google Maps : focus / LatLng to continent

Tags: google-maps

I am using Google maps JavaScript API.

Here is code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
         <html>
             <head>
                 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
                 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html;  charset=utf-8" />
                 <style type="text/css">
                     body {
                         font-family:  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                         font-size:10px;
                         margin:0;
                     }
                     #firstHeading  {
                        font-family: Calibri;
                         font-size:12px;
                        font-weight:  bold;
                        color: #0f9bec;
                     }
                    p {
                        color :  #666;
                     }
                 </style>

                 <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                     function  initialize() {
                         var  latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0442, 9.9116);
                         var  settings = {
                             zoom: 15,
                             center: latlng,
                             mapTypeControl: true,
                             mapTypeControlOptions: {style:  google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                             navigationControl: true,
                             navigationControlOptions: {style:  google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
                         var  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),  settings);


                         var  companyImage = new  google.maps.MarkerImage('/images/logo.png',
                             new google.maps.Size(100,50),
                             new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                             new google.maps.Point(50,50)
                         );

                         var  companyShadow = new  google.maps.MarkerImage('/images/logo_shadow.png',
                             new google.maps.Size(130,50),
                             new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                             new google.maps.Point(65, 50));

                         var  companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0442, 9.9116);

                         var  companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                             position: companyPos,
                             map: map,
                             icon: companyImage,
                             shadow: companyShadow,
                             title:"Høgenhaug",
                             zIndex: 3});

                       var infoWindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                        var  company='<div id="content">'+
                             '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                             '</div>'+
                             '<h1 id="firstHeading"  class="firstHeading">COMPANY</h1>'+
                             '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                             '<p>Content for company goes here.</p>'+
                             '</div>'+
                             '</div>';
                           google.maps.event.addListener(companyMarker,  'click',  function() {
                           infoWindow.setContent(company);
                           infoWindow.open(map,  companyMarker);
                           });

// List Go-on for other marker   
                }
                 </script>
             </head>
             <body onload="initialize()">
                 <div id="map_canvas"  style="width:500px;  height:300px"></div>
             </body>
         </html>
```

I have list of continent at the top of the map.

What I want is  Google Maps to focus on continent which user select.

Here is an [EXAMPLE](http://www.combell.com/en/domain-names/international-domain-names) of What I am looking at.

How can I achieve this within above code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is, Have a center point for each continent. When user selects a continent from the drop-down, you will have to center your map to that point. You can use:

```
map.setCenter(yourLocation);
```

For setting the center.. I hope this helps you. yourLocation is a object of LatLng type. You can create an object as follow:

```
var yourLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(-12.461334, 130.841904);
```

Comment: I think it is much better to set the zoom as well.Example map.setCenter(-12.461334, 130.841904, 10);